# Do I have multiple versions of OpenSSL on Ubuntu server 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, openssl

I have this Ubuntu server:

```
> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

This kernel:

```
> uname -a
... 4.4.0-83-generic #106~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP
```

(I think this combination release/kernel shouldn't exist)

The reported OpenSSL is this:

```
> openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
```

After some auto update, OpenSSL changed to `1.1.0f`. I still don't know how this happened. After this update `Tomcat 8.5` native library + APR started to have trouble.

Interestingly, the `phpinfo();` shows this:

> **openssl**
>
> ```
> OpenSSL support   enabled
> OpenSSL Library Version   OpenSSL 1.1.0f 25 May 2017     <-- expected
> ```
>
> **curl**
>
> ```
> cURL support  enabled
> ...
> SSL Version   OpenSSL/1.0.1f     <-- earlier version
> ```

Also, `OpenSSH` shows me this:

```
> ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

I don't know how `Curl` and `OpenSSH` are able to use the previous version of `OpenSSL`. I would love to make `Tomcat` do the same.

Do I really have multiple versions of `OpenSSL` in the server? Is there a way to check where these `1.0.1f OpenSSL` are been taken from? Also, how Ubuntu updated to this unsupported version `1.1.0f`?

I don't know what the below info mean, but might be useful:

```
> apt-cache policy openssl
openssl:
  Installed: 1.1.0f-2~ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 1.1.0f-2~ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.0f-2~ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.22 0
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.0.1f-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: You have installed 1.1.0f from the PPA ondrey/php/ubuntu (see the information in the version table). There might be some reason why you added this PPA to your apt sources. Some applications use this version, some others the default one (can't test as I don'thave two versions installed).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get rid of the version installed from the custom PPA?
Do you believe that Curl and OpenSSH are not using their own bundled OpenSSL but the one in the system?